# Angularjs nested ng-repeat with two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some `form_elements` which I use for ng-repeat, I have some `question.fields` which holds all fields for the nested loop.

For the binding of the form element (and the submission to the backend) I use a pregenerated array with objects:

```
review.values = []
obj = {};
obj['qid'] = question_id
obj['field_type'] = field_type
obj['val'] = ""
review.values.push(obj)

<div ng-repeat="element in form_elements">
    <div ng-repeat="field in element.question.fields">
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="review.values[$parent.$index*review.values.length].val" value="someval"> MyLabel</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to bind the correct `review.values[xyz].val` entry in the second loop?
`review values` is finally the array that gets saved.
I tried already with an helper function, that gets for me the right entry of review.values with the question_id without success.

Thanks, for any help.

Patrick

Comment: Setup a plunker ans will be faster to help you

Comment: What are you trying to do with the $parent.$index? If you want to find the position of your object in review.values, you should use an object that maps your form_elements and your fields to your review values instead of a list.

Comment: $parent.index was only a thought to calculate the position of the object, there are several objects in the review.values array? or how do you mean?